# How can I use "number placeholders" when using .replace()?

Tags: python

I have a file which has multiple instances of `"position": [num, num]` (`num` is a random number).

Now I want to replace those instances with `"position": [num, num, 0]`, so basically just add a `, 0` after the two numbers. But how can I do that?

I tried doing `text.replace('"position": [%d, %d]', '"position": [%d, %d, 0]')`. That didn't work though.

Comment: You probably want a _regular expression_, so you can replace based on the pattern rather than the exact text. Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3001761.

Comment: `text.replace(']', ', 0'])`

Comment: @KlasŠ. that won't work, because there are also other strings that use "]" in the file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to do the replacements ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/U5epU5/1)).

Edit for OP's comments:

Given that the file is fairly small, I'd iterate through it while reading, applying the substitution as I go, and then dump all the subbed lines into the same location.

```py
import re

file_path = "/tmp/74987707.txt"  # substitute your own

output_lines = []

with open(file_path, mode="rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        subbed_line = re.sub(
            r'("position": \[\d+(?:\.?\d*), \d+(?:\.?\d*))(])',
            r'\1, 0\2',
            line
            )
        output_lines.append(subbed_line)

with open(file_path, mode="wt") as f:
    f.writelines(output_lines)
```

Regex explanation:

1. group 1 `("position": \[\d+(?:\.?\d*), \d+(?:\.?\d*))`

- `(` start
- `"position": \[` match exactly (escaping `[`)
- `\d+` match one or more digit
- `(?:\.?\d*)` non capturing group, match a possible literal dot `.` and one or more digits
- `,`  match exactly
- `\d+(?:\.?\d*)` see above
- `)` end

2. group 2 `(\])`

- `(` start
- `\]` match exactly (escaping `]`)
- `)` end

Comment: An explanation of the regex would be good (I know regex101 gives you an explanation, but what if that link [rots?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot))

Comment: Fair enough, adding it now.

Comment: Where can I insert the string and what should I put for line, when the string is on only one line?

Comment: Do you intend to read the file and update it in place ? And how big is that file ?

Comment: @ljmc Yes. The file is 1463 KB big.

Answer (score 1):

From the structure of what you posted it looks like a json file, you can just loop through the items and append 0

```
import json

with open('example.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for item in data:
    if 'position' in item:
        if isinstance(item['position'], list) and len(item['position']) == 2:
            item['position'].append(0)

with open('example_modified.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```